# Can anyone guide me regarding Magento B2B store?

Tags: b2b, magento2-b2b

For setting up B2B Magento store. Do I need to buy some extension? or do Magento has built in B2B?

I don't have much knowledge so kindly guide me. Is any free or lower price extension available?

Comment: there is an extension Magento 2 B2B "magento/extension-b2b"